# IBOutlets are nil on a XIB view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, xib

I have a `UIView` subclass and it's corresponding XIB. I use this UIView in a `UITableViewCell` designed in Interface Builder. When dequeuing the cells, I have a correct reference from the cell to the custom view but the IBOutlets of the custom view are `nil`.

Here is a sample project that shows the problem

https://github.com/JanC/TestXIB

What am I doing wrong?

cheers,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's loading correctly. In the xib, I set the file owner to `TAItemTitleView` and the Class to just a UIView. I then load the xib in the `TAItemTitleView` itself

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
        self.view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:className owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
        [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
    return self;
}
```

https://github.com/JanC/TestXIB/blob/master/TestXIB/Classes/Views/TAItemTitleView.m

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it exactly works that way with UITableViewCell, defining it as IBOutlet won't load all the subviews so you have to load it from the bundle using [NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"" owner:self]; and assigned that to your item view

Comment: That's what I did ([see here](https://github.com/JanC/TestXIB/blob/master/TestXIB/Classes/Views/TAItemTitleView.m)) in the `TAItemTitleView` class but it creates an endless loop. I did the same as described in [this](http://www.maytro.com/2014/04/27/building-reusable-views-with-interface-builder-and-auto-layout.html) article

Comment: I've added just a normal view and the IBOutlet of the image view is also nil https://github.com/JanC/TestXIB/blob/master/TestXIB/Classes/Controllers/TAViewController.m#L24

Comment: You have to load from bundle inside your cell not from your same class that's why it goes on infinite loop! Since you are using initWithCoder every time it loads from the bundle it will call that same method again and hence the infinite loop!

Comment: How do I do that? Who is the "owner" of the nib to load?